# How to execute a function in nodejs and ejs templates using a button

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ejs

I want to execute a nodejs function in ejs template, the idea is when I click the button the function should be executed and the result should appear in the placeholder.  As shown in the screen shoot below:

[ejs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAApt.png)

I have embeded the function to the ejs file like below:

```
router.get('/lottery/generator', (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .render('generator', { generator: kaikkiController.uniqueRandomNumbers });
})
```

And then I tried to excute the function by click the button as shown in the `generator.ejs` file below:

```
<%- include('partials/header') -%>

<div class="container mt-5 w-50">
  <h2 class="mb-4">Generator</h2>

  <div id="true">RESULT SHOULD BE HERE</div>

  <button
    id="submit"
    onclick="<%= generator%>"
    class="btn btn-danger btn-block mt-3"
  >
    Generate
  </button>
</div>

<%- include('partials/footer') -%>
```

But I couldn't get the result of the excution. Any suggestion please?

Comment: what's `kaikkiController.uniqueRandomNumbers` is it a function defined in your Node.js backend?

Comment: Yes it is the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not confuse your server-side JavaScript code with the JS code that's being served to the front-end.

Express [renders](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) [EJS](https://ejs.co/) templates on the **backend** and sends them to your client (front-end).

So, it's not possible to call a function defined in your server-side (Node.js backend application) directly from the front-end, to do that consider creating an API endpoint that triggers that function, or look for a better option suited for your use case.

And in case you want to send a JS code snippet defined as a string in your backed:

You can pass that string to the `generator` variable, and then call it from your HTML. Or make that `generator` function an [`IIFE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), something like:

```js
const printRandomNumber = "(() => console.log(Math.random()))()"


eval(ejs.render(`<%- printRandomNumber %>`));
```

```html
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ejs@3.1.9/ejs.min.js
"></script>
```

> ### PLEASE DO NOT CONFUSE THIS `ejs.render` with `res.render`. In this example the rendering happens on the front-end.

Note that I'm using `<%-`:

> `<%-` Outputs the unescaped value into the template
> ([src](https://ejs.co/#docs-tags))

Then I used [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to evaluate that unescaped function string.

Also, please note:

> Warning: Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk. It is far too easy for a bad actor to run arbitrary code when you use eval(). See [**Never use eval()!**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!)

---

TLDR;

Avoid this. And find a better way to do it, by following one of these approaches:

- Creating an API endpoint that returns the results of your `kaikkiController.uniqueRandomNumbers`
- Send the necessary parameters from Express to the function you defined on the front-end and execute it safely there.
- Run the function code on the backend and only return the results.